# Pasar al siguiente valor en ForEach - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Amigos, tengo el siguiente problema.
Tengo un arreglo con 3 elementos los cuales debo consultar en una BD. Al momento de que alguno coincida con los registros de la base, necesito que el bucle se salte al siguiente valor del arreglo.

Lo que tengo hasta ahora es esto:

```
restAPI.query(function (adt) {
        $scope.areaDocumentTypes = adt;
        angular.forEach($scope.collection, function (dt) {
            angular.forEach($scope.areaDocumentTypes, function (item) {
                if ($scope.idArea == item.idArea && dt.idDocumentType == item.idDocumentType) {
                    if (!dt.selected)
                        //Código...
                }
                else
                    if (dt.selected)
                        //Código
            });
        });
    });
```

Traté con un *return* después del *else* pero no me funciono.

Cualquier sugerencia se agradece!

Comment: Disculpa, no comprendo, quieres que el bucle se detenga, si encontró lo que tu buscabas?? Por que si es asi, un `While` o un `Do While` seria la mejor opción, repito, si es lo que buscas

Comment: Quiero que el bucle pase al siguiente valor del array si encuentra lo que busco, se entiende mejor amigo?

Comment: A ver si loro entender, tu quieres que el bucle recorra el `array` de igual forma así encuentre lo que buscas dentro de el?

Comment: Pero una vez compruebe que coincide ya habrá pasado por ese registro, así que no se lo saltará si no que simplemente seguirá recorriendo tu arreglo.

Falta información quieres,  que luego esos valore se impriman, se guarden en otro arreglo?.

Comment: Trataré de ser lo más claro posible. Si ven el código tengo dos bucles anidados. El primero trae los registros de la tabla (**$scope.areaDocumentTypes**); el segundo trae los elementos del array (**$scope.collection**). Cuando llega al _if_ , esta comparando el primer elemento del array con el primer registro de la BD. Si esa condición da _true_ , quiero que pase al segundo elemento del array, y no que siga comparando el primer elemento del array con los demás registros de la BD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estás buscando es utilizar la instrucción "continue", que no está disponible en el bucle foreach. Una posible solución sería utilizar un flag (o bandera) para controlar la ejecución:

```
var continuar= true;
angular.forEach([0,1,2], function(count){
  if(continuar) {
    if(count == 1){
      continuar= false;
    }
  }else
      continuar= true;
});
```

Comment: Diste en el clavo!

Comment: Es inncesario poner banderas, solo usando `return` logras el mismo efecto. Ejemplo: https://repl.it/GPxl

Answer (score 0):

> **Nota:** siempre usa llaves en instrucciones aunque sea de una línea. No usarlas puede terminar en un error tipográfico, por ejemplo, si algún editor agrega o elimina por error un espacio/tab.

Para simular un `continue` en loops `forEach` simplemente usa `return` para evitar la iteración actual:

```
angular.forEach($scope.collection, function (dt) {
  if ($scope.idArea == item.idArea && dt.idDocumentType == item.idDocumentType) {
    if (!dt.selected) {
      // código normal
    }
    else {
      if (dt.selected) {
        return; // salta la interación actual en este punto
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación amigo!

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿por qué prefieres hacerlo con banderas si puedes simplemente utilizar `return` para saltar la iteración actual?

Comment: Lo probé con _return_ amigo y el problema insistía... sólo por eso.. también encuentro engorroso y poco "elegante" usar flags pero es lo que me funcionó

Comment: El problema es que no estás usando `return` en la condición correcta, si no reconoce el return, quiere decir **que nunca se está entrando a la condición**. Mira este pequeño código de muestra: https://repl.it/GPxl.

Comment: En [éste enlace](https://jsbin.com/catojulije/edit?js,console) puedes ver el mismo ejemplo usando `Angular.forEach`